# Is it possible to write a program that uses different SDK-s?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am writing a program which uses Kinect and Kinect SDK 1.8. Today I had a chance to play with Kinect V2 and Kinect SDK 2.0.

Is it possible to write a program which can use both of the SDK-s depending on which Kinect is connected? Or is it just wiser to write a separate program for Kinect V2 and not bother with mixing SDK-s?

Comment: Is the 2.0 SDK backwards compatible with the older Kinect model?

Comment: @DavidG, I don't think it is. In 2.0 there are more joints on the tracked person. I wrote a simple program for Kinect v2, it does not work with the older Kinect

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, yes. You need to develop your app against abstractions, though. Use the `Adapter` pattern to "unify" the SDKs' interface, i.e. write one (or more) adapter(s) for each SDK that share the same interface. Write your business logic against that interface then.

To run the program, implement a factory that returns the correct adapter depending on which kind of device is connected.